# How these kind of coding tutorial videos can be made using ANIMATION with your face shown on screen?

Tags: video, video-editor

I was preparing for an interview and came across this wonderful YouTube channel called Tap Academy. In their videos, the tutor's explanation is amazing, and he uses animations on a whiteboard to teach concepts. As he speaks, the animations appear, making it visually appealing (I'm unsure if these animations are pre-scripted). In my opinion it would be very difficult to prepare a script before hand (and I doubt animations are created even before the video begins).

Another YouTube channel that employs a similar approach is The Modern Coder. They are excellent at teaching git concepts using animation. The instructor demonstrates code in his editor while typing simultaneously. Whenever he wants to illustrate a concept, an animation suddenly appears on the screen, making it easy to understand.

My question is, what tools do they use to create such videos? Initially, I thought it might be PowerPoint animation, but PowerPoint may not have advanced options like displaying people on the screen and synchronizing animations with speech.

I also came across coding video tutorials on Udemy by Scott Barrett, where he explains coding using only animations without showing his face. These videos are incredibly helpful, as they allow for easy visualization of complex concepts and understanding of why and how they work. Learning to code becomes much easier with this style of videos.

After some research, I found that Adobe After Effects can be used to create such animation videos (I have no knowledge about AE), but I'm still uncertain about how the first two YouTube videos I mentioned were created using Adobe AE. Are there other tools specifically designed for creating these types of videos?

I haven't been able to find any resources on YouTube or Google that explain how to create these kinds of videos, so I would appreciate any insights on the tools and techniques used.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, Screenflow gets you a long way there: https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for your input.